# Prove that $f'(1)+f'(-1)=0$

Tags: functions

If $f$ is a differentiable function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x+y),f(x)f(y),f(x-y)$ (taken in that order) are in arithmetic progression for all $x,y$ belonging to Real numbers and $f(0)$ is not equal to $0$ then we have to prove that $f'(1)+f'(-1)=0$ .

MY try :
$$f(x+y) + f(x-y) = 2f(x)f(y)$$
$$f'(x) = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{f(x+y) - f(x-y)}{2y} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{2(f(x+y) - f(x)f(y)}{2y} = \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{f(x) - f(x)f(0)}{y}$$
In order for this limit to exist, $f(0) = 1$.

I am unable to solve further .

Comment: You can't replace $y$ by $0$ in half an expression and leave $y$ in the other half.

Comment: Take original equation $f(x+y)+f(x-y)=2f(x)f(y)$ and let $y=0$ first.

Comment: You have already a long experience with the site, I think here the time to finally learn Latex. It is really not so complex.

Answer (score 3):

If $f$ is identically $0$, then the answer is clear.

Otherwise, let $x$ be such that $f(x)\neq 0$ and let $y=0$: this gives you $f(0)=1$.

Now let $x=0$ and $y$ be arbitrary: $f(-y),f(y), f(y)$ are in arithmetic progression, therefore $f(y)=f(-y)$ for all $y$, meaning that the function is even.

For an even differentiable function you have $f'(x)+f'(-x)=0$ for any $x$.

Comment: it's given that $f(0) \ne 0$

Comment: @Vasya Right. But it doesn't really matter as shown above.

Comment: @AmaudMortier: That's right. I upvoted your solution, just thought that the the first sentence was unnecessary.